# MomentJS rounding up seconds to minute - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datetime, momentjs

I have a time picker, where the user inputs a period of time expressed in decimal (`8.5 for example for 8h30min`), but he can also input manually "from" and "to" periods,

so for example -> `from: 08:00,  to: 17:30` and the data that will pass is always in decimal, `8.5` in this case.

Then I have a function that converts that decimal in time and shows it as string somewhere.

The problem is that the seconds aren't rounded up, for example if you put:
`9.23`, in hours that is `9h 13min 48sec`, the function will return this string: `9h13min`, which is rounded down, but I want it to always round it up.

Can't figure what to change in my function, tried adding 1min and then use startOf('minute') but it doesnt seem to work with `duration`

here is the function, it recieves a number, which is the hours in decimal:

```
getDurationAsString(hours: number): string {
            if (!hours || hours <= 0) return "";

            const mDuration = moment.duration(hours, "hours");
            return `${mDuration.asHours() > 0 ? Math.floor(mDuration.asHours()) + "h " : ""}${mDuration.minutes() > 0 ? mDuration.minutes() + "m" : ""}`;
        }
```

so the problem lies here `mDuration.minutes() + "m"`

how can I round to the top a duration with momentJs?

Comment: round it manually after detecting an overflow: `!!mDuration.seconds() ? mDuration.minutes()+1 : mDuration.minutes()`

Comment: I solved it like this:
'${mDuration.minutes() > 0 ? (mDuration.minutes()+(mDuration.seconds() > 30 ? 1 : 0)) + "m" : ""}`'

thank you for the input anyway!

Comment: @AJ989 -- If you solved it yourself, please add your solution as an answer to this question, and accept it. This will help future readers of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
'${mDuration.minutes() > 0 ? (mDuration.minutes()+(mDuration.seconds() > 30 ? 1 : 0)) + "m" : ""}`'
```

thank you for the input anyway!